# Cannot create a database and table

Tags: typescript, sqlite, ionic-framework

My mobile app via Ionic uses SQLite during offline mode. I'm using Angular and Typescript. On my service it logs an Android emulator error:

> Error - No database has been created

Does SQLite accept interface or models to create tables? My service code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { SQLite, SQLiteObject } from '@awesome-cordova-plugins/sqlite/ngx';
import { ValidationService } from './validation.service';

interface CustomerData {
  id?: any;
  customerNo: any;
  customerAccountNo: any;
  customerName: string;
  customerAddress: string;
  customerContactNo: string;
  customerEmail: string;
  customerSeqNo: any;
  customerMeterNo: string;
  customerRate: any;
  customerStatus: string;
  customerZone: any;
  customerPa: number;
  customerSeptage: any;
  customerSeptageAmount: number;
  customerPipe: string;
  customerContractNo: string;
  customerDeposit: number;
  customerRsNumber: string;
  customerClassification: string;
  customerSaddleSize: string;
  installDate: string;
  connectionDate: string;
  customerBranch: string;
  startReading: number;
  discoFlag: number;
  reactivateFlag: number;
  disconnectionDate: string;
  discoJoNo: string;
  reactivateDate: string;
  lastReadingDate: string;
  totalBill: number;
  currentBillMonth: string;
  previousReading: number;
  presentReading: number;
  CUM: number;
  advancePayment: number;
  promiFlag: number;
  promiAmount: number;
  promiBillMonth: string;
  septageJO: string;
  serviceDate: any;
  surveyJO: string;
  surveyDate: any;
  csrFlag: number;
  statusFlag: number;
  deficit: number; // stores deficit Amount
  paymentFlag: number; //allowsPayment to push thru
  septicFlag: number; // determines if customer is qualified for septic
  rsFlag: number; // triggers when rs has been issued
  refundFlag: number; // triggers when refund has been processed
  customerReadStatus: number; // triggers if the account has been read for the billing month
  nwsc: any; // actual placeholder for reactivate date
  customerMeterSize: any; // NWRB report
  customerSurveryDate: any; // Date of NWSC Survey
  customerSurveyor: any; // Name of the SWSI Surveyor
  oldMeterNo: any; // used for meter change etc
  oldPrevious: number; // used for meter change etc
  oldPresent: number; // used for meter change etc
  scFlag: number; // Senior Citizen Flag
}

interface LedgerData {
  id?: any;
  customerNo: any;
  customerAccountNo: string;
  customerBillMonth: string;
  customerName: string;
  customerAddress: string;
  customerMeterNo: string;
  customerRate: any;
  customerZone: any;
  customerSequence: any;
  customerPA: boolean;
  customerClassification: string;
  customerFRdate: string;
  customerParticular: string;
  customerSeptage: number;
  customerSeptageFlag: number;
  customerBranch: string;
  collectorName: string;
  collectorCode: string;
  waterBillFlag: any; // determines if its waterbill or other charge
  collectionDate: any; // vanilla date
  transactionDate: any; // with time
  customerPaymentAmount: number; // if with other transaction
  customerWaterBillSum: number; // vanilla waterBill
  customerBillNo: number;
  customerPaymentStatus: boolean;
  scDiscount: number;
  otherDiscount: number;
  otherDiscountDetails: string;
  totalDiscount: number;
  rsNumber: number;
  contractNumber: number;
  customerPresent: number;
  customerPrevious: number;
  customerCUM: number;
  customerBilling: number;
  deviceReader: string;
  contractrorA: any; // reserve
  contractrorB: number; // reserve
  contractrorC: any; // reserve
  contractrorPaymentTotal: number; // reserve
  promiPayAmount: number;
  promiFlag: number;
  promiBillMonth: string;
  promiTotal: number;
  advancePayment: number;
  otherChargesAmount: number;
  feeAmount: number;
  otherCharge: any;
  fees: any;
  depositAmount: number;
  deficitAmount: number;
  refundAmount: number;
}

interface UserData {
  id?: any;
  readerName: string;
  billMonth: string;
  billDisc: any;
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class DatabaseService {
  constructor(private sqlite: SQLite, private validate: ValidationService) {}

  createDatabaseIfNotExists(): Promise<SQLiteObject> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const db = this.sqlite.create({
        name: 'swsi_drops.db',
        location: 'default',
      });

      this.checkIfDatabaseExists(db)
        .then(() => {
          this.createTables(db);
          this.validate
            .showPrompt('System Alert', 'Database Created')
            .then(() => resolve(db))
            .catch((error) => reject(error));
        })
        .catch((error) => reject(error));
    });
  }

  private checkIfDatabaseExists(db: Promise<SQLiteObject>): Promise<any> {
    return new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
      db.then((dbInstance: SQLiteObject) => {
        const tableNames = ['customerData', 'ledgerData', 'userData'];
        const promises = tableNames.map((tableName) =>
          dbInstance.executeSql(
            `SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name='${tableName}'`,
            []
          )
        );

        Promise.all(promises)
          .then((results) => {
            const tableExists = results.every(
              (result) => result.rows.length > 0
            );
            if (tableExists) {
              console.log('Database exists');
              this.validate.showPrompt('System Alert', 'Database Exist');
              resolve();
            } else {
              reject(new Error('Database or table does not exist.'));
            }
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            reject(error);
          });
      });
    });
  }

  private createTables(db: Promise<SQLiteObject>): Promise<any> {
    return new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
      db.then((dbInstance: SQLiteObject) => {
        const createTableQueries = [
          this.getTableCreationQuery<CustomerData>('customerData'),
          this.getTableCreationQuery<LedgerData>('ledgerData'),
          this.getTableCreationQuery<UserData>('userData'),
        ];

        const promises = createTableQueries.map((query) =>
          dbInstance.executeSql(query, [])
        );

        Promise.all(promises)
          .then(() => {
            console.log('Tables created successfully');
            this.validate.showPrompt(
              'System Alert',
              'Tables created successfully'
            );
            resolve();
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            this.validate.showPrompt('System Alert', error);
            reject(error);
          });
      });
    });
  }

  private getTableCreationQuery<T>(tableName: string): string {
    const model = {} as T;
    const columns = Object.keys(model).join(',');

    return `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ${tableName} (${columns})`;
  }
}
```

Component that uses the service:

```
this.databaseService
              .createDatabaseIfNotExists()
              .then((db) => {
                console.log(db);
              })
              .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
              });
```